# VS Solution Explorer Analyzers exclamation: ef1000 "possible sql injection vulnerability"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Strange message in Solution Explorer.

ef1000 "possible sql injection vulnerability"

[image]

It doesn't prevent compile, no errors, no warnings, no messages in "Errors List".

No similar messages in the output on compile...
Click doesn't move focus to "vulnerability" line. No referenced file/line related information.

But there is context menu with "Delete" button which doesn't work (nothing happens). There are no Analyzers related entries in proj file.

Looks like common package references bug. How to fix it?

Comment: That looks like a code analyzer (provided by a nuget package) that generated a warning.  Check the Error List window for the actual warning it generated (make sure you don't have warnings filtered out), and fix the code that it is warning you about.

Comment: That is the point: no errors in error list... All filters were removed...

Comment: Do you know what nuget package provided the analyzer? Hmm... Closer examination of the screenshot makes it look like it is part of EF Core directly.

Comment: You could remove the `microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers` package from your project, but you might lose other useful functionality it provides.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I went to that location C:\Users\User.nuget .. etc and deleted the package.  I closed visual studio and reopened it.  The package was restored and the error was gone.  I was using a .net framework application in visual studio at the same time and was opening and closing the core solution repeatedly so I'm thinking the package got corrupted somehow.

Comment: I also had to run Update-Package -reinstall at the package manager console

Answer (score 8):

Just unload the project and reload it again, the warning is disappeared.
[The source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13512#issuecomment-450725483)

**UPDATE for Visual Studio 2019:**

If you use Visual Studio 2019 you have always to get last version. So if there are any updates available just install it.

Click on Help => Check for Updates => Update.

Comment: Worked for me. Simple solution